# How do I get data with Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I want to do http.get internally when onCall in Firebase Cloud Functions and return the corresponding zip code.
And I want to call from Flutter.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
let http = require('https');
admin.initializeApp();
exports.postalCode = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    //const URL = "https://zipcloud.ibsnet.co.jp/api/searchzipcode="+data.text;
const URL = 'https://zipcloud.ibsnet.co.jp/api/search?zipcode=100-0002';
var data = [];
http.get(URL, (res) => {
    let body = '';
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body += chunk;
        data.push(body);
    });

    res.on('end', (res) => {
        return data[0];
    });
    }).on('error', (e) => {
        console.log(e.message); //when Error
    });   
});
```

What's wrong?
Thank your support.

Answer (score 0):

can you use node-fetch instead, it will be easier

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

admin.initializeApp();
exports.postalCode = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const URL = 'https://zipcloud.ibsnet.co.jp/api/search?zipcode=100-0002';
    return (await fetch(URL)).json();

});
```

Comment: Is it possible call from flutter  and get from flutter ???

Comment: I can't use node-fetch.

[error]
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/nagayamasaru/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.

Why???